# Cannot assign int in Dask array

Tags: python, arrays, dask, assign

I'm having trouble doing a simple operation: assigning a value to a dask array. I get the error:
"Item assignment with <class 'int'> not supported"

Does anybody know why ?
This should normally be doable according to the [dask documentation](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/array-assignment.html)...

Here's the (elementary) "chunk" of code that I'm having trouble with. Problem occurs because of the line "x[0] = 1.0"

```
import dask.array as da

x = da.zeros(10)
x[0] = 1.0
```

If you read this message and know how to help me that'd be really nice ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Works for me - so this is probably an issue with the version of Dask that you are using.

```
$ python
Python 3.10.8 (main, Nov 24 2022, 14:13:03) [GCC 11.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dask
>>> import dask.array as da
>>> x = da.zeros(10)
>>> x[0] = 1.0
>>> x.compute()
array([1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
>>> dask.__version__
'2022.7.0'
```